# Standard utilities notation for SYNOPSIS sections

Tags: documentation

I want to construct a program utility synopsis for optional comma separated keywords.

```
utility [KEYWORD[,KEYWORD]...]
```

I worder where I should put the repeating pattern `...`.

I want to allow the following usage

```
utility
utility keyword
utility keyword,keyword
utility keyword,keyword,keyword 
and so on
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this correctly, but if you're looking for advice on  programming, you should try [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I want to construct the program synopsis for the documentation of my program.

Answer (score 0):

I think the style you're proposing is very clear and you should use it.

The documentation of allowable arguments isn't well-specified anywhere, it builds on conventions, and I'd argue that your solution fits these conventions relatively well.

For comparison, the useradd man page uses

```
-G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
```

and I think that is actively more confusing than what you are doing! So stick with yours.